# How .data + .text section can be = How much flash the final program will consume

Tags: avr, flash

I could not understand one point related with Arduino code.

Let's say i have following code

```cpp
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("foo");
}

void loop() 
{
   
}
```

When i compile above code for Arduino Uno. Arduino IDE gives.

> Sketch uses 1478 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256
> bytes. Global variables use 192 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving
> 1856 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

I examine the generated file with `avr-size`.

```
.data                         26   8388864
.text                       1452         0
.bss                         166   8388890
.comment                      17         0
.note.gnu.avr.deviceinfo      64         0
.debug_aranges               208         0
.debug_info                 6150         0
.debug_abbrev               2721         0
.debug_line                 2239         0
.debug_frame                 504         0
.debug_str                  1770         0
.debug_loc                  1908         0
.debug_ranges                 80         0
```

As you can see .data + .text = consuming program storage space. Then i checked this document. https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep567/04sp/pdfs/avr-libc-user-manual.pdf. It says about `avr-size`

```
Note:
The avr-size program (part of binutils), coming from a Unix background,
doesn’t account for the .data initialization space added to the .text section, so in
order to know how much flash the final program will consume, one needs to add
the values for both, .text and .data (but not .bss), while the amount of pre-allocated
SRAM is the sum of .data and .bss.
```

Then, i check contents of .data section with

```
avr-objdump.exe -s -j .data <my.elf>
```

Then I got

```
Contents of section .data:
 800100 00000000 ff005f00 8c004c01 bd009b00  ......_...L.....
 800110 af00666f 6f000d0a 0000               ..foo.....
```

I'm confused, what above quote really means ? "foo" stored in .data section, but why i need to add this section to .text section in order to calculate how much flash consumes ?

Comment: Where do you think those string literals are stored?

Comment: @KIIV in SRAM ?

Comment: SRAM is volatile, meaning it can't remember anything without being powered

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on what JRobert said, variables which are initialized, and other literals (eg. the word "foo" in your example) have to come from somewhere, and thus are stored in program (flash) memory and copied into RAM as part of the C++ initialisation.

However, uninitialised variables do not take up flash memory. Compare:

```c++
char foo [1000];
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("foo");
  Serial.print (foo);
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

This reports for the Uno:

```
Sketch uses 1498 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1192 bytes (58%) of dynamic memory, leaving 856 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

However if you initialise that global variable foo, like this:

```c++
char foo [1000] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("foo");
  Serial.print (foo);
}

void loop() 
{ 
}
```

Now the flash takes 1000 more bytes:

```
Sketch uses 2498 bytes (7%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1192 bytes (58%) of dynamic memory, leaving 856 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

This clearly shows that, since uninitialised variables at global scope are set to zero, the compiler has generated code to do just that. However initialised variables have to be copied from flash into RAM.

A very useful technique when using these chips with not much RAM is to use the "F" macro, which effectively tells the compiler to copy strings directly from flash, rather than into RAM, thus saving RAM space. For example:

```c++
Serial.println (F("Hello, world"));
```

In this case the string "Hello, world" still has to be in flash, but doesn't have to be copied into RAM, thus saving precious memory for other purposes.

---

## Putting initialised arrays into flash

I've got a lengthy discussion about using PROGMEM for storing data, other than just literal strings for printing [on my forum](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12615).

This example code here shows how you can store messages in PROGMEM (flash memory) and retrieve them at runtime. It uses `pgm_read_word` to read the pointers, and then `strcpy_P` to copy the string from PROGMEM into RAM, so it can then be printed.

```c++
const int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 10;

const char Message0000 [] PROGMEM = "Twas bryllyg, and ye slythy toves"; 
const char Message0001 [] PROGMEM = "Did gyre and gymble"; 
const char Message0002 [] PROGMEM = "in ye wabe:"; 
const char Message0003 [] PROGMEM = "All mimsy were ye borogoves; And ye mome raths outgrabe."; 
const char Message0004 [] PROGMEM = "\"Beware the Jabberwock, my son! \n The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!"; 
const char Message0005 [] PROGMEM = "Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun\n The frumious Bandersnatch!\""; 
const char Message0006 [] PROGMEM = "He took his "; 
const char Message0007 [] PROGMEM = "vorpal sword in hand:"; 
const char Message0008 [] PROGMEM = "Long time the manxome foe he sought - "; 
const char Message0009 [] PROGMEM = "So rested he by the Tumtum tree, \n And stood awhile in thought."; 

const char * const messages[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS] PROGMEM = 
   { 
   Message0000, 
   Message0001, 
   Message0002, 
   Message0003, 
   Message0004, 
   Message0005, 
   Message0006, 
   Message0007, 
   Message0008, 
   Message0009, 
   };

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  
  unsigned int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
    char * ptr = (char *) pgm_read_word (&messages [i]);
    char buffer [80]; // must be large enough!
    strcpy_P (buffer, ptr);
    Serial.println (buffer);
    count += strlen (buffer) + 1;
    }   // end of for loop

  Serial.print (F("String memory used = "));
  Serial.println (count);

  }  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

This particular example doesn't use much RAM:

```
Sketch uses 2220 bytes (6%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 188 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1860 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The values of your initialized-data (.data) are stored in flash together with your code. The initialized-data gets copied to RAM after every upload, reset, or power-up, before your code starts executing.

Comment: That's why the F("macro") and overloaded methods in Arduino core exists to avoid this RAM "spam". However Atmega4809 doesn't need it as it has all memories mapped into single address space. Or ARM based boards doesn't need this.

Comment: @JRobert, Interesting behavior. So everything in the .data segment eats from the flash area, right?

Comment: @embeddedstack, the flash memory in MCU is the 'hard drive'

Comment: Yes - the .data segment contains the variables for which you have specified initial values. Those values have to be stored in non-volatile memory to initialize the variables in RAM before execution begins.